# jQuery check if div contain text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var el = $('#solving'); 
   //var el = $('#solving:contains("Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")');   
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Checking if el has text");
      if (el.text() == 'Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...'){
        console.log("Reloading");
      }
    },2000);
});
```

but in log's i see, that it doesn't work, i didn't see logger's Reloading even if page contain:

```
<div id="solving">
          Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...
        </div>
```

also i try:

```
$('#solving:contains("Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")')
```

what wrong? How to check my div on present of some text?

Comment: Rather than checking for a text. I would add a class to the status "wait...etc" and then check for the class using the `hasClass()` function o jQuery.

Comment: @Alvaro maybe yes... give jsfiddle please

Comment: You have to add the class when you add the text to the page. I dont know how you do it and therefore i can not give you a concrete answer.

Comment: @Alvaro how to check, on what set hasClass method?

Comment: Just  `if($('#element').hasClass('myClassName')){ ...`

Comment: @Alvaro this is not working for such html: <div id="solving">
          <div class="wait">
            Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...
          </div>
        </div>     and for such js: if($('#solving').hasClass('wait')){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
if ($('#solving:contains("Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")').length > 0) {
  // found
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8644K/1/. Even if your selector contains `:contains(...)`, it's just a selector. That does not change the return value of `$(<selector>)` to a boolean, which still remains a list of potentially matched objects. Therefore, you can check how many of these matched objects could be found.

As the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) says, *Select all elements that contain the specified text.*

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code works 2 sec interval .I have changed to 400 ms.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var el = $('#solving'); 
   //var el = $('#solving:contains("Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")');   
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Checking if el has text");
      if (el.text().indexOf("Wait!") != -1){
        console.log("Reloading");
      }
    }, 400);
});
```

Comment: when i have wait, i must go in... but you set here !=

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
el.text().trim()== 'Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...'
```

You have to strip the new line character as you started the text with next line to

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/f4PQM/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var el = $('#solving'); 
   //var el = $('#solving:contains("Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")');   
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Checking if el has text" + el.text());
      if (el.text().trim() == 'Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...'){
        console.log("Reloading");
      }
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: That does not work if the element contains any other text than the one he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use trim() with el.text() because div text has whitespace.

```
  var el = $('#solving');
  //var el = $('#solving:contains("Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")');   
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Checking if el has text");
      if (el.text().trim() == 'Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...'){
        console.log("Reloading");
      }
    },2000);
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J93mr/) : http://jsfiddle.net/J93mr/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your div contains spaces in the beginning of it's content  , so you should delete spaces using `$.trim()`  like this : **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fUMxR/)**

```
  if ($.trim(el.text()) == 'Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...'){
    console.log("Reloading");
  }
```

But solution using `length()` is better as suggested by @Remo :

```
if ($('#solving:contains("Wait! Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...")').length > 0) {
          console.log("Reloading");

}
```

Comment: The `:contains` selector already solves this problem, without any trimming.

Comment: @Remo the problem is not in contains , it's in the text of the div which is compared with a trimed string

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fPaxU/1/

```
el.text().trim()
```

All you need is a simple 'trim'